# Consultar de varias tablas

Tags: php, sql

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código pero no me funciona. Estoy intentando traer información de 3 tablas:

```
 $result  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.ID,a.proveedor,a.peso,a.fecha,b.ENTRADA,b.cajas,b.peso,b.pagado,c.ENTRADA,c.monto FROM a entradas b separacion c pagos WHERE b.ENTRADA=a.id AND c.ENTRADA=a.id") or mysqli_error($con);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $arr[] = $row;
    }
```

el problema es que lo ejecuto desde PostMan y me marca:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in  <linea de error> while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: Ha probado la consulta SQL, ¿retorna datos directamente en MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

El error puede ser porque la `query mysql` este mal.

Puedes utilzar las sentencias `JOIN` de `mysql`. Puedes consultar la documentación [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Te dejo unos ejemplos:

> SELECT * FROM a JOIN b LEFT JOIN c ON (c.key=a.key) LEFT JOIN d ON
>   (d.key=a.key) WHERE b.key=d.key;
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (column1) WHERE t2.column2=5;

Toda la información está sacada de la [Documentación de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)